# Changing existing date time field

Tags: 8, entities, datetime

I am working on an already existing site that has content.

There is a content type with field date and time. **I need to remove the time component and just be Date only** without deleting any content along the way. If the time data is lost, that is fine.

Can I simply delete the field and recreate it with date only? Or will that delete the existing data?

[image]

Comment: `will that delete the existing data?` yep, any time you delete a field, all the data is deleted as well.

Comment: This maybe can be done with config. Export current config, change as desired, reimport. Otherwise create another field, migrate the data, then delete the old field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as suggested, programmatically changing the config won't work, as all dates will show empty. Which explains why it's locked in the UI.

You'll need to browse your DB and find the `node__{field_date}` table and manually remove the time part for all values.

[image]

Then make a sql export of this table.

Repeat the above with `node_revision__{field_date}`.

In Drupal, manage fields, delete your field_date. Recreate field_date with Date only. Import your sql db table exports you had made.

Flush cache in Drupal.